# Can a program be written to find information of a server from its IP address?

Tags: networking, ip, whois

I am trying to automate getting details of a particular server. Right now, I use a website based service like [this](https://www.infobyip.com/ip-%20104.123.204.11%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.html), and was hoping if there is a way to automate it. Any ideas and insights on this would be helpful.

I also found a few websites that provides their API but they are paid. So I am open to suggestions to any open source tools that can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I found a program from Microsoft that you can download. It's part of the sysinternals suite, it's called WHOIS, and it's usable in the dos prompt.

It looks like it's possible to do the same thing by writing your own program.
Microsoft uses whois.google.com to get the information.

In the past I used google maps api to map out delivery addresses, so I'm sure you can come up with a good way to make a program that behaves like the one in the question.

Here's the url link to download it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/whois

After unzipping it, copy and paste it into the c:\windows\system32 folder.
As soon as it's copied in the folder, you can go into dos and type in:

```
whois -v something.com
```

and this will produce this info:

Whois v1.21 - Domain information lookup
Copyright (C) 2005-2019 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - [www.sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com)

Connecting to COM.whois-servers.net...
Server COM.whois-servers.net returned the following for SOMETHING.COM

Domain Name: SOMETHING.COM
Registry Domain ID: 57672_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.google.com
Registrar URL: http://domains.google.com
Updated Date: 2021-05-22T19:53:23Z
Creation Date: 1995-07-28T04:00:00Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2024-07-27T04:00:00Z
Registrar: Google LLC
Registrar IANA ID: 895
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: registrar-abuse@google.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.8772376466
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Name Server: COLEMAN.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM
Name Server: DINA.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN Whois Inaccuracy Complaint Form: https://www.icann.org/wicf/

> > > Last update of whois database: 2022-07-22T14:55:33Z <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp

NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the
registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is
currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration
date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring
registrar.  Users may consult the sponsoring registrar's Whois database to
view the registrar's reported date of expiration for this registration.

TERMS OF USE: You are not authorized to access or query our Whois
database through the use of electronic processes that are high-volume and
automated except as reasonably necessary to register domain names or
modify existing registrations; the Data in VeriSign Global Registry
Services' ("VeriSign") Whois database is provided by VeriSign for
information purposes only, and to assist persons in obtaining information
about or related to a domain name registration record. VeriSign does not
guarantee its accuracy. By submitting a Whois query, you agree to abide
by the following terms of use: You agree that you may use this Data only
for lawful purposes and that under no circumstances will you use this Data
to: (1) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass
unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations via e-mail, telephone,
or facsimile; or (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes
that apply to VeriSign (or its computer systems). The compilation,
repackaging, dissemination or other use of this Data is expressly
prohibited without the prior written consent of VeriSign. You agree not to
use electronic processes that are automated and high-volume to access or
query the Whois database except as reasonably necessary to register
domain names or modify existing registrations. VeriSign reserves the right
to restrict your access to the Whois database in its sole discretion to ensure
operational stability.  VeriSign may restrict or terminate your access to the
Whois database for failure to abide by these terms of use. VeriSign
reserves the right to modify these terms at any time.

The Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and
Registrars.

Connecting to whois.google.com...
Server whois.google.com returned the following for SOMETHING.COM

Domain Name: something.com
Registry Domain ID: 57672_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.google.com
Registrar URL: https://domains.google.com
Updated Date: 2021-05-22T19:53:23Z
Creation Date: 1995-07-28T04:00:00Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2024-07-27T04:00:00Z
Registrar: Google LLC
Registrar IANA ID: 895
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: registrar-abuse@google.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.8772376466
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://www.icann.org
/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Registry Registrant ID:
Registrant Name: Contact Privacy Inc. Customer 7151571251
Registrant Organization: Contact Privacy Inc. Customer 7151571251
Registrant Street: 96 Mowat Ave
Registrant City: Toronto
Registrant State/Province: ON
Registrant Postal Code: M4K 3K1
Registrant Country: CA
Registrant Phone: +1.4165385487
Registrant Phone Ext:
Registrant Fax:
Registrant Fax Ext:
Registrant Email: https://domains.google.com
/contactregistrant?domain=something.com
Registry Admin ID:
Admin Name: Contact Privacy Inc. Customer 7151571251
Admin Organization: Contact Privacy Inc. Customer 7151571251
Admin Street: 96 Mowat Ave
Admin City: Toronto
Admin State/Province: ON
Admin Postal Code: M4K 3K1
Admin Country: CA
Admin Phone: +1.4165385487
Admin Phone Ext:
Admin Fax:
Admin Fax Ext:
Admin Email: https://domains.google.com/contactregistrant?domain=something.com
Registry Tech ID:
Tech Name: Contact Privacy Inc. Customer 7151571251
Tech Organization: Contact Privacy Inc. Customer 7151571251
Tech Street: 96 Mowat Ave
Tech City: Toronto
Tech State/Province: ON
Tech Postal Code: M4K 3K1
Tech Country: CA
Tech Phone: +1.4165385487
Tech Phone Ext:
Tech Fax:
Tech Fax Ext:
Tech Email: https://domains.google.com/contactregistrant?domain=something.com
Name Server: COLEMAN.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM
Name Server: DINA.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/

> > > Last update of WHOIS database: 2022-07-22T14:54:41.137303Z <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit
https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/epp-status-codes-2014-06-16-en

Please register your domains at: https://domains.google.com/
This data is provided by Google for information purposes, and to assist
persons obtaining information about or related to domain name registration
records. Google does not guarantee its accuracy.
By submitting a WHOIS query, you agree that you will use this data only for
lawful purposes and that, under no circumstances, will you use this data to:

1. allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass
   unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations via E-mail (spam); or
2. enable high volume, automated, electronic processes that apply to this
   WHOIS server.
   These terms may be changed without prior notice.
   By submitting this query, you agree to abide by this policy.